# Return partial string matches in Angular 5 http GET request

Tags: node.js, angular, http

I need to return all partial matches to the `userName` string from a GET request.

Currently it only returns a user if the userName is a direct match. The user should be able to type in part of the userName and the GET request should return all matches to the inputted string.

**Service:**

```
path = this.basePath + '&UserId=' + data.userName;

let requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers(),
        search: new URLSearchParams()
    };

return this.httpClient.get(path, requestOptions)
    .map((response: any) => {
        return response.json();
    }).catch(this.dataService.handleError);
```

Comment: This sounds like a server-side issue and not client-side (i.e. Angular) issue. Have you looked at that code to make changes in what you are querying from your data store?

Comment: @Robert - You have make an pattern matching query for the database. For example Query for mySql database `SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName LIKE 'InputString%'; . This query will fetch all the rows where value starts with "InputString". 
`